# Xamarin UITest ios Exception when installing app: Failed to Install app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

i have problem when trying to run Xamarin.UITest on the ios simulator. When I start test locally and pass the app bundle, after while i got Exception DeviceAgentException: Failed to install app /path/to/App.app

I'm running this code:

```
return ConfigureApp.iOS.DeviceIdentifier("04096CC6-B8D0-4C1C-A4CB-4F4CABCFE3D1").AppBundle("/path/to/App.app").StartApp();
```

And got this error:

```
SetUp : Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : Failed to install app /path/to/App.app

ExitCode: 134
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ba9766b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff62ce8942 objc_exception_throw + 48
    10  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff638ff015 start + 1
    2   iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001058fa378 +[Command resourcesFromArgs:] + 0
    3   iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001058f3a79 +[Codesigner adHocSign:resourcesToInject:] + 509
    4   iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001058f33ae +[Codesigner resignApplication:withProvisioningProfile:withCodesignIdentity:resourcesToInject:] + 153
    5   iOSDeviceManager                    0x0000000105900d88 -[Simulator installApp:mobileProfile:codesignIdentity:resourcesToInject:forceReinstall:] + 324
    6   iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001059012fd -[Simulator installApp:resourcesToInject:forceReinstall:] + 67
    7   iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001058f1d57 +[InstallAppCommand execute:] + 876
    8   iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001058fd222 +[CLI process:] + 1111
    9   iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001058e863d main + 121
(
)
*** First throw call stack:
2018-12-20 16:35:28.395 iOSDeviceManager[2555:42598] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CBXException', reason: 'Error codesigning /path/to/App.app: '
App com.acme.appid is not installed on 04096CC6-B8D0-4C1C-A4CB-4F4CABCFE3D1
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Stack trace:
 at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchAppLocal (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, System.Boolean clearAppData) [0x001e2] in <fd164790b61b4dd4848a99fcb06e7e4b>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, Xamarin.UITest.TestCloud.TestCloudiOSAppConfiguration testCloudAppConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient testCloudWsClient, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient xtcServicesClient, System.Boolean testCloudUseDeviceAgent) [0x00068] in <fd164790b61b4dd4848a99fcb06e7e4b>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Execution.IExecutor executor) [0x002af] in <fd164790b61b4dd4848a99fcb06e7e4b>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00000] in <fd164790b61b4dd4848a99fcb06e7e4b>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in <fd164790b61b4dd4848a99fcb06e7e4b>:0
 at MobileTesting.AppInitializer.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Platform platform) [0x00022] in /Users/bh185120/OneDrive - NCR Corporation/MobileTesting/MobileTesting/AppInitializer.cs:17
 at MobileTesting.Tests.BeforeEachTest () [0x00001] in /Users/bh185120/OneDrive - NCR Corporation/MobileTesting/MobileTesting/Tests.cs:27
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
 at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0003b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

**Update:**

/path/to/App.app is just example, i have full path to my app in the code i'm running

I'm using this versions of apps/os/frameworks:

- Macos High Sierra
- Xcode 10.1
- iOS 12 (simulator)
- Xamarin.UITest 2.2.7

Comment: No i just put it there as example, i have there full path to the app package in my code

Comment: Try just normally deploying the app to the simulator first, i.e. not running the tests, but just deploying for debugging. Then once installed, run your tests.

Comment: Tried to do this and run tests by app bundle id...says same thing for device runner.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace again, it seems to be some signing issue. Does the app install when you deploy it for debugging (not running tests)? Are your UITest  NuGet packages updated, both in the App and the test Project ? (but don't update Nunit NuGet package past version 2.6.4 as v3.0 of Nunit is not supported)

Comment: I have native ios app and it works fine

Comment: Did you try using the `InstalledApp` configuration instead of `AppBundle`? E.g. `return ConfigureApp.iOS.DeviceIdentifier(".<deviceid>").AppBundle("<appbundleid>").StartApp();` replacing <deviceid> with the device id and <appbundleid> with your app's bundle id?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. That gave this same error with device runner.